# Drupal path issues with Wamp

Tags: path, drupal-7, wamp, wampserver

I just installed drupal 7 on my local wamp installation and was trying to override the user registration form however it gives me the following error:

```
include failed (C:\wamp\www\d7/themes/bartik\templates/user-registration-form.tpl.php)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this forward backslash errors on wamp. Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php predefined constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR where you are creating any static path
Example: 
$path =drupal_get_path('theme',$GLOBALS['theme']);
$mypath = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.templates.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.user-registration-form.tpl.php;